# AppleScript to launch and loop a video full screen avoiding menu bar

Tags: video, applescript, fullscreen

I'm trying to run this applescript:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    open alias "Users:ebowen:Desktop:MOUND_1.32GB_h264.mov"
    play the front document
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "QuickTime Player"
    set frontmost to true
    tell menu bar item 5 of menu bar 1
        click menu item "Enter Full Screen" of menu 1
        click menu item "Loop" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

on a mac mini running OSX 10.6.8 and it works except if it runs automatically when starting up.

When running from start-up, the mac's mouse pointer defaults to positioning itself over the apple menu and this leaves the menu bar still visible over the full-screen mov

I need to avoid all that and have it play full-screen with no menu bar automatically. Any pointers?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, although I haven't gone to the effort of restarting my computer and seeing if it solves the specific issue.

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    tell (open POSIX file "/Users/ebowen/Desktop/MOUND_1.32GB_h264.mov")
        set looping to true
        present
        play
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid it didn't work, I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to resort to switching on mouse keys in accessibility preferences and then applescript keystrokes to move the cursor away from the apple.